# Cómo definir el espaciado entre las columnas al exportar datatables en pdf

Tags: javascript

estoy trabajando con datatables.net, utilizo makepdf para exportar a pdf. Cómo puedo personalizar el espacio entre las columnas?

Gracias de antemano.

Este es el código.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var table = $('#datatable').DataTable({
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            dom:'<"col-md-offset-10"B><lf><t><ipr>',
            buttons: [
                {
                    extend:    'pdfHtml5',
                    download: 'open',
                    text:      'PDF',
                    message: 'Información de Documento.',
                    title: '{% block title_report %}Reporte{% endblock title_report %}',
                    pageSize: 'LEGAL',
                    exportOptions:
                    {
                        modifier: {
                            page: 'current'
                        }
                    },
                    customize: function(doc)
                    {
                        doc.styles.fontSize = 16;
                        doc.pageMargins = [ 59, 50, 59, 50 ];
                        doc.defaultStyle.border='solid';
                        doc.styles.tableHeader.fillColor = '#d0e9c6';
                        doc.styles.tableHeader.alignment = 'center';
                        doc.styles.tableBodyEven.alignment = 'center';
                        doc.content.splice( 0, 0, {
                            margin: [ 0, 0, 0, 12 ],
                            alignment: 'left',
                            image: 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0....gAAA'
                        } );
                    }
                }
            ],
            content:[
                {
                    columns: [
                        {
                            width: 100
                        }
                    ],
                    columnGap: 10
                }
            ]
        });
     });
```

Comment: publica el código que estás intentando, así con gusto la comunidad de SOes te ayuda a completar la función que deseas :D dale una lectura a : http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour y http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask por cierto, bienvenida al sitio :D

Comment: ok,gracias fredyfx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes intentar darle un espaciado a cada columna que quieras, por ejemplo:

```
sTitle: "id",
mDataProp: "id",
sWidth: '100%'
```

Lo que hago aquí es darle un espacio por columna, en el ejemplo puse `100` pero si no ves alguna diferencia puedes subir más el porcentaje. Lo máximo que he puesto en un tamaño fue de `550` para ver una diferencia de tamaño significativa, puede que esto afecte el tamaño de la columna a la hora de la exportación.